# Send FB invite to website from iOS/Android app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, invite, fbsdk

Looks like it's a popular place to get stuck, but nevertheless I've not found an up-to-date solution neither in FB docs nor here.

I need to send invite to FB app that has no Canvas platform from my Android app.

1. As I can see, sending `AppInviteContent` through `AppInviteDialog` is not an option (invite is successfully sent but never reach the 
   addressee also it works fine if I add Canvas platform to FB app).
2. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

> If your app is not a game and has a mobile or web presence:
>   You can also use the Message Dialog on iOS and Android...

But sending `ShareLinkContent` through `MessageDialog` doesn't work - `canShow() == false` for it.

Maybe there is a 3rd approach to do the job (using Android FB SDK)?